# Trying to import python file to main python file but got Import error in rpi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to import a python file to main.py.

test1.py

```
def some_func():
   print ('Test1')
if__name__ == '__main__':
   service_func()
   test1.some_func()
```

main.py

```
import test1
def service_func():
   print('Service func')
if__name__ == '__main__':
  service_func()
  test1.some_func()
```

This code can works in windows but it cannot work on RPI 3. The error message is ImportError: No module name test1.

Please kindly assist.

Thanks

Comment: Change the import test1 to from test1 import * and it still doesn't work

Comment: Did you start it from console? Are both files in the same dir?